# Google Play Services (RESULT_LICENSE_FAILED)

Tags: java, android, google-play-games, leaderboard

I have created an app and a service (service for Leaderboard), everything works fine with leaderboard when i am signed in with my tester google account. When i change to another account it show me:

> RESULT_LICENSE_FAILED Error=3 Code=10003

p.s.1 My service is fully published

p.s.2 My updated app (implementing Google Play Services -Leadeboard) is not published at Play Store.

Do you think that if i publish my updated app will be working fine, or i have to check something else?

Comment: Did you enable anti piracy  in the linked application when you setup your game? https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy This can cause that error when not downloading the app from the play store.

Comment: Thank you very much @ClaytonWilkinson. That was the answer! I was searching about 6 hours now and i didn't though about that. Thank you again.

Comment: I think that @ClaytonWilkinson should write that comment as an answer and the OP should accept it so other members will be benefited from this knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Enabling anti piracy in the linked application when you setup your game could cause this, see https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/antipiracy 
This can cause that error when not downloading the app from the play store.